# Dell XPS 13 on Debian very difficult to start

Tags: debian, startup, shutdown, suspend

I cannot shutdown my Dell XPS 13 laptop without having the hardest time starting it again later.

## Behavior

I call `sudo shutdown now` from a terminal. The computer seems to shutdown. The battery lasts quite a short time however, this tells me that it may not achieve a proper shutdown.

Restarting the laptop after that is very difficult, as illustrated in [this recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rSX4q-kV0i8). Spoiler: it's me pressing the power button with varying down press times, the LED lighting up, then down, or not at all, or delayed... but the screen does not come on. Sometimes it takes 15 minutes of that treatment before it turns on.

This happens with or without the external power supply connected.

## Clues

Here is the latest shutdown, triggered with a `sudo shutdown now` from a gnome terminal, file `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Dec 25 12:36:13 vinden systemd[1]: Got message type=method_call sender=:1.139 destination=org.freedesktop.systemd1 path=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager me
mber=GetDynamicUsers cookie=2 reply_cookie=0 signature=n/a error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Dec 25 12:36:13 vinden systemd[1]: Sent message type=method_return sender=n/a destination=:1.139 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=1019 reply_cookie=2 signature=a(us) error-name=n/a er
ror-message=n/a
Dec 25 12:36:16 vinden systemd[1]: Bus private-bus-connection: changing state UNSET → OPENING
Dec 25 12:36:16 vinden systemd[1]: Bus private-bus-connection: changing state OPENING → AUTHENTICATING
Dec 25 12:36:16 vinden systemd[1]: Accepted new private connection.
Dec 25 12:36:16 vinden systemd[1]: Bus private-bus-connection: changing state AUTHENTICATING → RUNNING
Dec 25 12:36:16 vinden systemd[1]: Got message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.systemd1 path=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager membe
r=StartUnit cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 signature=ss error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Dec 25 12:36:16 vinden systemd[1]: poweroff.target: Trying to enqueue job poweroff.target/start/replace-irreversibly
Dec 25 12:36:16 vinden systemd[1]: Added job poweroff.target/start to transaction.
Dec 25 12:36:16 vinden systemd[1]: Pulling in systemd-poweroff.service/start from poweroff.target/start
Dec 25 12:36:16 vinden systemd[1]: Added job systemd-poweroff.service/start to transaction.
Dec 25 12:36:16 vinden systemd[1]: Pulling in system.slice/start from systemd-poweroff.service/start
Dec 25 12:36:16 vinden systemd[1]: Added job system.slice/start to transaction.
Dec 25 12:36:16 vinden systemd[1]: Pulling in -.slice/start from system.slice/start
Dec 25 12:36:16 vinden systemd[1]: Added job -.slice/start to transaction.
Dec 25 12:36:16 vinden systemd[1]: Pulling in shutdown.target/start from systemd-poweroff.service/start
Dec 25 12:36:16 vinden systemd[1]: Added job shutdown.target/start to transaction.
```

## Questions

1. How do I go about debugging this? What are more logs that may give
   me a lead of what is going on?
2. When this has happens, what is a procedure that would help me recover, a way to to a harder shutdown, so that a following power up
   would work every time? When the computer eventually starts, I get
   the startup screen with time-out, which lets me start with
   alternative command arguments. A way to consistently come to that
   screen would be better than nothing.
3. `sudo shutdown now` seems to fail to trigger an actual shutdown. Why is that? What can I do to make sure `shutdown` shuts
   down for real?
4. I understand that resume from suspend nearly always is a problem. Is there something to do to make it work, or is it a lost cause? Doesn't this sound related?

Comment: I seriously doubt this is a Debian or OS problem.  Knowing Dell a little, have you tried removing and putting back the battery.  Well, I see it's not as easy as with a real laptop.  Just remove the connector and put it back.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I have actually swapped the battery with a new one, due to swelling. I had the issue before the swap, still had after. But I agree this can be a HW issue.

Comment: Try reseating every connector you can find, memory too.